# Disable xHCI by another way than BIOS - USB 3.0

Tags: usb, syslinux

I'm having troubles with the communication between a NXT-Lego device and a Notebook with USB 3.0 port.

I affirm that the problem is the USB 3.0 - driver, because this same device with another Notebook very similar, a pretty older model with only USB 2.0 works.

Notebook, System info:
2 port USB 2.0
1 port USB 3.0, 
SO: Ubuntu 12.04
kernel: 3.8.0-33-generic

My approach to resolve this communication problem, is force the notebook to see all the usb pot as USB 2.0.

Now the SO load for all usb port, xhci_hcd driver, but I want SO load ehci_pci (USB 2.0) driver.

How i can achieve that ? Another way than by BIOS, because this notebook BIOS hasn't this configuration option.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried updating the BIOS?  You could also try blacklisting the "xhci_hcd" driver.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`lspci -nn | grep USB  | cut -d '[' -f3 | cut -d ']' -f1 \
| xargs -I@ setpci -H1 -d @ d0.l=0`

`sudo` is required.

With that comamnd you change your 3.0 ports to 2.0. More info [here](https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1908/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux).

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me to a similar sounding problem was to simply use a 2.o Hub in between.
I'm not sure this would have solved the OP's issue ( 4.5 years ago ) but it's an easy thing to try.